# Python 2.7.12 netaddr.IPNetwork AddrFormatError

Tags: python, cidr

Version: Python 2.7.12
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1
Kernel: 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP
Arch: ppc64le

netaddr.IPNetwork fails with:
**netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: invalid IPNetwork '9.2.0.0/16'**

I have a function:

```
def innet2(ip, net):
    print("ip: "+ip, "net: " + net)
    ip = IPAddress(ip).value
    print("ipnew: " + str(ip))
    network = IPNetwork(net)
    print("network-first: " + str(network.first))
    print("network-last: " + str(network.last))

    if ip >= network.first and ip <= network.last:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If I call this function at the beginning of my program for debug purposes
and it executes properly:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    FLAGS(sys.argv)
    startSSH()

    print ("service ssh finished")
    isParamReady = False
    hostsStr = ""
    isChef = False

    for i in range(0, 100):

        time.sleep(20)

        print("test: " + str(innet("9.2.132.186", "9.2.0.0/16")))
        print("test2: " + str(innet2("9.2.132.186", "9.2.0.0/16")))
        print("test2: " + str(innet2("10.1.3.2", "9.2.0.0/16")))
        isParamReady, hostsStr, isChef = **getHostIpStr()**
        break

    if (isParamReady is True and isChef is True):
        execCommand(hostsStr)
    else:
        waitOrExit()
```

When it is called from getHostIPStr() it generates the AddrFormatError

```
def getHostIpStr():
    hostsStr = "-host "
    isChef = False
    print("namespace= " + namespace)
    print("FLAGS.job_name= " + FLAGS.job_name)
    print("FLAGS.network= " + FLAGS.network)
    ps_pods = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace, label_selector="job="
                                     + FLAGS.job_name)
    job = v1batch.list_namespaced_job(namespace,   label_selector="job="
                                      + FLAGS.job_name)
    worker_num = job.items[0].spec.parallelism
    items = ps_pods.items
    print("items=  ", len(items))
    print("worker_num=  " + str(worker_num))
    if (len(items) < worker_num):
        return False, "", False
    for i in range(0, len(items)):
        podIp = items[i].status.pod_ip
        print("podIp:" + podIp)
        print("localIp:" + localIp)
        if (i == 0 and podIp == localIp):
            isChef = True
        hostIPs = getIp(podIp)
        net = FLAGS.network
        print("len of Ips: " + str(len(hostIPs)))
        for j in range(0, len(hostIPs)):
            print("j: " + str(j), "hostIPs[j]: " + hostIPs[j],
                  "network: " + FLAGS.network)
            ip = hostIPs[j];
            res = innet2(ip, net)
            if (res is True):
                podIp = hostIPs[j]
                hostsStr = hostsStr + podIp
                break
        if (i < len(items)-1):
            hostsStr = hostsStr + ","
    return True, hostsStr, isChef
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my problem.

I was passing a quoted network address and IPNetwork was failing when trying to convert the octet from of ip address into decimal format because the first octet had the string quote in it.